# How do I loop through multiple elements and attach a click function on each?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to loop through a number of elements in a ruby on rails app so that a div can be shown or hidden dependant on which element is selected in a dropdown (or radio buttons or whatever).

My javascript/coffescript knowledge is poor but after a couple of days hacking at it I have a working solution, although it is horribly constructed.

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  if $('select[id="open_closed[1]"]').val() == "0" or $('select[id="open_closed[1]"]').val() == "1"
    $('#open_close_times_1').hide()
  $('select[id="open_closed[1]"]').click ->
    if $('select[id="open_closed[1]"]').val() == "0"
      $('#open_close_times_1').hide()
    if $('select[id="open_closed[1]"]').val() == "1"
      $('#open_close_times_1').hide()
    if $('select[id="open_closed[1]"]').val() == "2"
      $('#open_close_times_1').show()

  if $('select[id="open_closed[2]"]').val() == "0" or $('select[id="open_closed[2]"]').val() == "1"
    $('#open_close_times_2').hide()
  $('select[id="open_closed[2]"]').click ->
    if $('select[id="open_closed[2]"]').val() == "0"
      $('#open_close_times_2').hide()
    if $('select[id="open_closed[2]"]').val() == "1"
      $('#open_close_times_2').hide()
    if $('select[id="open_closed[2]"]').val() == "2"
      $('#open_close_times_2').show()
.
.
.
return
```

This is for setting opening times for days of the week for a store so the following snippet extends up to open_closed[7]. I'm sure this should be done with a loop, rather than writing each one out. I also have a "holidays" version of this which will have an arbitrary number of days - so this solution falls down completely there, but a loop would be perfect.

I've been trying to extract this into some sort of loop to achieve the same effect (so I can do this up to 7 here and the other code up to an arbitrary max), but I can't find a tutorial or instructions which allow me to do this. This is day 4 of my hacking at this so any pointers would be gratefully received, what do I need to do to refactor this into a sensible solution?

Comment: You should be able to use a less specific selector which will return an array of nodes. Then you can loop through the array to hide the content and add the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, get an array of the select items you are targeting with a less specific selector. For example you can use a starts with selector. Then loop through the results to hide the element and add an on click event.

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  var options = $("select[id^='open_closed']");
  $.each(options, function(index, item){
    if ($(item).val() == 0 || $(item).val() == 1) {
      $(item).hide();
    }

    $(item).on("click", function() {
      var open_close_selector = "#open_close_times_" + (index + 1);
      if ($(item).val() == "0" || $(item).val() == "1"){
        $(open_close_selector).hide();
      } else {  
        if ($(item).val() == "2") {
          $(open_close_selector).show();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This can be cleaned up a bit, but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: I tried the code you have above, but couldn't get it working.. I have managed to get some code hacked together that works and is shorter than my original. I'm not even sure its actually better but, as usual with coffeescript/javascript I've lost the will to live so it can stay as it is until I have the time/inclination to learn it properly. Thanks for the consideration and help!

Comment: OK, I wasn't happy with the solution I had hacked together out of bits of string and cardboard as it required adding various ids and classes into the html and was getting to be a bit of a mess. So I had another look at the solution you started above and with a bit of reworking my solution is now a lot better - thanks margo! I'll add my final code as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

OK - so with a bit of reworking and inspired by margo's answer this is what worked for me:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  options = $('select[id^=\'open_closed\']')
  $.each options, (index, item) ->
    open_close_selector = '#open_close_times_' + index
    if $(item).val() == '0' or $(item).val() == '1'
      $(open_close_selector).hide()
    $(item).click ->
      if $(item).val() == '0' or $(item).val() == '1'
        $(open_close_selector).hide()
      else
        if $(item).val() == '2'
          $(open_close_selector).show()
      return
    return
  return
```